# Local maxima or minima of a continuous functions

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to disprove/prove the following claim:

Let $f:[0,1] \to R$ be a continious function, such that:

$$f(0.5) < f(0) < f(1) $$

Prove that there exists a **local** minima or maxima to $f$.

It seems so simple to prove. Since its continuous then $f(0)$ is a maxima or otherwise there must be a point near it which is, since its point which is lower then others in the given region.

Unfortunately, I failed to figure out a formal proof.

Comment: A much more general result holds. Having a continuous function on a compact domain alone grants the existence of local minima **and** maxima without any additional conditions. The name of this result is "extreme value theorem".

Answer (score 1):

Since your function is continuous in $[0,1]$, it has a minimum and a maximum necessarily.

Lemma 1:
Since $f$ is continuous, there is no $\xi$ such that $\lim _{x\rightarrow \xi} f$ that does not exist or is equal to $\pm \infty$, since for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$, the limit exists and is equal to $f(\xi)$. Hence, $f$ is upper and lower bounded.

Take a line parallel to the $x$ axis, that is $y=a\in\mathbb{R}$, and find the $a$ which is the upper bound of $f$. There is no way that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f=a$ and $f(x_0)\neq a$, since $f$ is continuous. This function is also continuous at 0 and at 1, so you don't have to worry about what happens at 0 and at 1.

In your problem, specifically, you can find a $\xi \in (0, 1)$ such that $f$ has a global minimum at $\xi$. The function cannot have a global minimum at 0, or 1, since you have already found a value that is less than both. But $f$ has a global min, we have shown this before. $\therefore,\ \exists \xi \in (0, 1):\ f $ has a global minimum at $\xi$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, it has at least one global minimum in this interval. Since $f(0.5)\lt f(0)$ and $f(0.5)\lt f(1)$, any such global minimum is not at an endpoint, so it must be a local minimum.

Comment: I can understand it by reason , but i don't feel its formal proof yet.

Comment: We have *used but not proved* the fact that a continuous function on a closed bounded interval has a global min (and global max). This is a very standard theorem that you probably already have. The rest is basically fully justified in the above answer. For it is clear from the definition of local min that a global min attained in the interior of our interval is a local min.